# What are the differences between selichah, mechilah and kaparah?

Tags: tefilla, kavana-intent, forgiving-mechilah

In reflecting on these three terms, selichah, mechilah and kapparah, they are often thought of simply as synonyms of forgiveness.

But trying to focus on their specific meanings in the context of the judgment of the Heavenly Court and how they are used in the liturgy of Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur suggests that they are actually three different and distinct requests which apply to different circumstances.

In particular, when considering the conclusion of the confession of Yom Kippur which speaks of the סלחן לישראל and the מחלן לשבטי ישרון, the first two categories. But then goes further requesting no suffering, afflictions or severe illnesses, which would suggest a connection to kapparah.

How are we to understand the meaning of what we are asking from G-d, the Creator of us all?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=696982572466524

Answer (score 2):

The [Shaloh](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Yoma%2C_Ner_Mitzva.1.46) explains that they're increasing level of forgiveness corresponding to decreasing levels of sinfulness:

> **כפרה לחטאים. ומחילה לעונות. וסליחה לפשעים**

> שחטא הוא השוגג מתפללים
> שימחקם לגמרי כאלו לא היו מעולם. וזה ל' כפרה כמו אכפרה
> פניו וגו'. ומחילה לעון כי שם נשאר שום רושם. וסליחה שהיא אריכות אף
> לפושעים הם המורדים כי עליהם יום הכפורים תולה

> For חטא, which is an inadvertent sin, we pray that He should erase
> them completely, like they never happened. This is [indicated by] the
> term כפרה, similar to "I will appease him." (Genesis 32:21) [The
> weaker term] מחילה corresponds to עון, because it leaves some trace
> behind. סליחה connotes clemency to פושעים, the wanton sinners, because
> Yom Kippur only suspends [judgement] for them.

Comment: You might want to write this in translation and maybe give some illustrations. But it’s a good start.

Comment: I added my own translation. The illustrations I'll leave to illustrators.

Comment:  I didn’t mean pictures. I meant examples! You’re funny.

Comment: I’ve also been reflecting on different circumstances related to transgression like in a courtroom. There are those who are law abiding, but err in judgment. They believe they were justified in their choice. There are also those who know they are transgressing but are compelled for a variety of reasons. Finally, there are those who are in rebellion. They neither care, nor believe they are wrong. By court judgement they have no defense. For them, the only recourse is to be held harmless  at the mercy of the court. In this sense, כפרה is like כפרת, to cover something from being seen.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Interesting, but that's the opposite of my quote.

Comment: I don’t see anything “opposite” from the Sheloh. If you look at the source from Bereshit he quotes, it sounds like it agrees with what I wrote concerning the meaning of kapparah. The only question I see is if Rav Peretz  Segol is quoting Rema accurately. The confusion seems to be coming from there.

Comment: I believe the Roshei Teivot are speaking about Rabbi Pinchas HaLevi Horowitz of Prague AKA  Munka Pinchas AKA Rabbi Pinchas Segal who was the son-in-law of the Rema.

Comment: What is עון? If חטא is inadvertent and פשע is not a mistake?

Comment: @larry909 I'm not sure. If פשע is spiteful sin, maybe עון is an ordinary sin, motivated by desire.

Answer (score 1):

In the back of the Artscroll Machzor on Yom Kippur (p.860) on the part of vidui where we read:

> ועל כֻּלָּם אֱלֽוֹהַּ סְלִיחוֹת. **סְלַח** לָֽנוּ. **מְחַל** לָֽנוּ. **כַּפֶּר** לָֽנוּ
>
> And for all of these, G-d of pardon, pardon us, forgive us, grant us atonement.

It writes as follows:

> This is a progression from a smaller to a greater degree of forgiveness. סלח, *forgive us*, i.e. give up the right to punish us, מחל, *pardon us*, i.e. do not even harbour resentment or ill will against us; and כפר, *atone for us*, i.e. remove any effects of our sin as if we had never committed them. (***Abarbanel***)
>
> According to ***Malbim*** and ***R' Hirsch***, these terms go from a greater degree of forgiveness to a smaller degree. סלח connotes total forgiveness; מחל means a permanent waiver of the right to punish, even though the sin has not been completely forgiven; כפר - from כפרה, *cove*r - implies only that the sin is hidden from sight, so that the punishment is suspended temporarily.

In *[Pathway to Prayer](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578194698.html)* by Rabbi Mayer Birnbaum he adopts the first approach, and translates it as:

> סְלַח לָֽנוּ - Forgive us for the sins themselves
>
> מְחַל לָֽנוּ - Pardon us for the insult caused to Your Honor by our sins
>
> כַּפֶּר לָֽנוּ - (and) atone for us as if they had never occurred.

Comment: I’m liking the development of this answer Dov. It occurs to me that in the disposition of a trial in court there two initial stages (charges and plea), followed by presentation of evidence and trial, and then the closing two stages, the judgement and the sentencing. Judgement is the status of the accused after presentation of evidence (guilt or innocence). Sentencing is the determination of penalties and restitution that may be applied to one who is found guilty. How does this apply to the question?

Comment: Different nuschaot have different orders for those three words in the different places they appear in the liturgy.

Answer (score 0):

Selicha—forgiveness.

Mechila—annulment of debt. Completely as if wrongdoing never happened.

Kapara—retribution. Taking payment for the debt. Punishment to result in forgiveness.